# How to make footnotes appear at bottom of the footer's bar?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes

How to make footnotes appear at bottom of the footer's bar?

Code:

```
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

AJAX\footnote{Asynchronous JavaScript and XML permet de construire des applications Web et des sites web dynamiques interactifs sur le poste client.}
```

Made:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the length `\footskip` to a suitable value, e.g.

```
\setlength{\footskip}{17pt}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\footskip}{17pt}

\begin{document}

AJAX\footnote{Asynchronous JavaScript and XML permet de construire des applications Web et des sites web dynamiques interactifs sur le poste client.}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want your footnotes under the foot rule, they will overwrite the page number...

In this case I suggest to delete the line

```
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

and to redefine `\footnoterule`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern23\p@
  \hrule\@width\linewidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern23\p@
  \hrule\@width\linewidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

AJAX\footnote{Asynchronous JavaScript and XML permet de construire des applications Web et des sites web dynamiques interactifs sur le poste client.}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to write footnotes under the lowest foot bar?

Comment: The footskip that you have written will damage the final display of a report. Because, that bar will be mixed with the table just above. Have you please a better idea?

Comment: PERFECT! What about the space under the footnote?

Comment: Is it possible to remove it and place it over the footer bar?

Comment: @user3289501 I've edited the answer. Note, however, that the spacing depends on the contents of the page.

Comment: I'm using yout first MWE, here is it's outputs on different pages : [first page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8D0ox.png), [second page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HPNoG.png) & [third page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzky3.png).